# Trying to Samba share on Linux, but the Macos can't see it

Tags: server, samba

The config in /etc/samba/smb.conf looks right and the Mac can see the share, but the data underneath the share are invisible. Login credentials are refused. (And, yes, the credentials I provided are correct for the Linux box.) Undoubtedly some little config thingy that I've not stumbled into yet.

For completeness:

```
[global]
        workgroup = KORBHOME
        netbiosname = bach
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        printcap cache time = 750
        cups options = raw
        usershare allow guests = Yes
[photos]
        comment = Photographs
        path = /home/Pictures
        browseable = yes
        read only = No
        create mask = 644
        inherit acls = Yes
```

Kubuntu 21.10 -- firewall disabled, as I am behind a router that blocks everything.

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It has been too long since I first set up Samba and the instructions for doing it that I first encountered did not emphasize that Samba has its own password processing code. Clever:

> sudo smbpasswd -a $USERNAME

[type in the password a couple of times]

> sudo smbpasswd -e $USERNAME

the password now exists and has been enabled.